# How to use Async and Await with AWS SDK Javascript

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I am working with the AWS SDK using the KMS libary. I would like to use async and await instead of callbacks.

```
import AWS, { KMS } from "aws-sdk";

this.kms = new AWS.KMS();

const key = await this.kms.generateDataKey();
```

However this does not work, when wrapped in an async function.

How can i use async and await here?

Comment: `await` requires a promise; that takes a callback.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If you are using aws-sdk with version > 2.x, you can tranform a `aws.Request` to a promise with chain `.promise()` function.
For your case:

```
  try {
    let key = await kms.generateDataKey().promise();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

the `key` is a `KMS.Types.GenerateDataKeyResponse` - the second param of callback(in callback style).

The `e` is a `AWSError` - The first param of callback func

note: `await` expression only allowed within an async function

Comment: How can one access `key` outside of the try statement?

Comment: @mbspark you can create `key` variable at first, outside of the `try` block. But, why?

Comment: I wanted to use `key` elsewhere in the program. I did end up figuring out what I was trying to do in a different way, though.

Answer (score 18):

`await` requires a `Promise`.  [`generateDataKey()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KMS.html#generateDataKey-property) returns a [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html), not a `Promise`.  `AWS.Request` are `EventEmitters` (more or less) but have a [`promise`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) method that you can use.

```
import AWS, {
  KMS
} from "aws-sdk";

(async function() {
  const kms = new AWS.KMS();
  const keyReq = kms.generateDataKey()
  const key = await keyReq.promise();

  // Or just:
  // const key = await kms.generateDataKey().promise()
}());
```

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021 I'd suggest to use [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html). It's a rewrite of v2 with some great new features

sample code:

```
const { KMSClient, GenerateDataKeyCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-kms');

const generateDataKey = async () => {
  const client = new KMSClient({ region: 'REGION' });
  const command = new GenerateDataKeyCommand({ KeyId: 'KeyId' });
  const response = await client.send(command);
  return response;
};
```

**AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 new features**

- [modular architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/modular-packages-in-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) with a separate package for each service
- [First-class TypeScript support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/first-class-typescript-support-in-modular-aws-sdk-for-javascript/)
- [New middleware stack](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/middleware-stack-modular-aws-sdk-js/)