# Node.JS - Why is await not waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await

I'm using a lambda function in AWS to do some work and I need the function get some data from the AWS SSM resource in order to complete the work.  However I'm struggling to get the code to wait for the call to `getParameter` to wait until the call back has completed prior to moving on.

I've tried structuring the code in two different ways.

[Structure reference #1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/nodejs-write-lambda-function-example-full.html)

[Structure reference #2](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Neither way seems to get the execution to pause.

With my current implementation which is built on "Structure reference #2" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const ssm = new aws.SSM();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

console.log(event.headers);

var webhook = JSON.parse(event.body);
var key = "";

var parameterRequest = ssm.getParameter( {
 Name: "param1",
 WithDecryption: true
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log(err);    
    }
    else
    {
        key=data.Parameter.Value;    
        console.log(data);
    }
});

await parameterRequest;

var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(JSON.stringify(webhook)).digest('hex');
console.log("HASH: sha1=" + hash);
console.log("Key:" + key);
}

const response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusDescription": "200 OK"
    };
    return callback(null, response);
```

Why would the `console.log("HASH: sha1=" + hash);` and `console.log("Key:" + key);` get executed prior to the `console.log(data);`?

**Update 7/2/2019**

Await and Promise applied without the try catch:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const ssm = new aws.SSM();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

console.log(event.headers);

var webhook = JSON.parse(event.body);
var key = "";

var parameterRequest = await ssm.getParameter( {
 Name: "param1",
 WithDecryption: true
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log(err);    
    }
    else
    {
        key=data.Parameter.Value;    
        console.log(data);
    }
}).promise();

var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(JSON.stringify(webhook)).digest('hex');
console.log("HASH: sha1=" + hash);
console.log("Key:" + key);
}

const response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusDescription": "200 OK"
    };
    return callback(null, response);
```

Comment: `await` only does something useful when you await a promise.  It has no magic powers to make something else wait.  It seems likely your function does not return a promise so `await` doesn't do anything.  Either wrap your own promise around the interface and find out how to get a promise out of the interface you have.

Comment: Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328292/how-to-use-async-and-await-with-aws-sdk-javascript/51328537#51328537

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SSM.getParameter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameter-property) does not return `Promise` directly, it returns an `AWS.Request`. You can use [`AWS.Request.promise()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) to consume the request as a promise.

```
try {
    const data = await ssm.getParameter({
        Name: "param1",
        WithDecryption: true
    }).promise();
    console.log(data);

    const key = data.Parameter.Value;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: That works well to make it a serialized flow.  I applied the await and promise changes to my original code and the log statement for the key got fired twice.  Do you happen to know why that would happen?

Comment: The log statement should not fire more than once, I can't say for sure without seeing your new code though.

Comment: I updated the post with the new code by adding the await and promise.

Comment: You shouldn't use the callback if you're using promises, the AWS client likely calls the callback *AND* resolves the promise. You should omit the callback in favor of try/catch and consume the data from the `parameterRequest` variable.