# scan duplicates item with DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to scan items and avoid to use duplicates code.

so, I am trying to use `for-of` asynchronously for it.

```
async function checkDupl(){
  const arr = new Array(10).fill(0);
  let code = '';
  for(const i of arr){
    //generate RANDOM CODE
    //for example, it would be '000001' to '000010'
    code = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1).toString().padStart(6,"0");
    const params = { ... }; // it has filterExpression the code I generated randomly
    await DYNAMO_DB.scan(params, (err, res) => {
      if(res.Items.length === 0) {
        /* no duplicate! */
        return code;
      }
    }); 
  }
  return code;
}

console.log(checkDupl());
// it always return '';
```

What I have missed or misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` just waits a Promise (or `thenable` object), but you are using `await` with a "void" function (You use `DYNAMO_DB.scan` as a callback styte function).

My suggestion, Use `DYNAMO_DB.scan` with Promise style ([The way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328292/how-to-use-async-and-await-with-aws-sdk-javascript/51328537#51328537))

```
async function checkDupl() {
  const arr = new Array(10).fill(0);
  let code = '';
  for (const i of arr) {
    //generate RANDOM CODE
    //for example, it would be '000001' to '000010'
    code = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1).toString().padStart(6, "0");
    const params = { ... }; // it has filterExpression the code I generated randomly

    const res = await DYNAMO_DB.scan(params).promise(); // convert to promise

    if (res.Items.length === 0) {
      /* no duplicate! */
      return code;
    }
    return code;
  }
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await checkDupl());
})();
```

Comment: Do you think the code is the best? I don't think so, especially `const arr` is useless. So, can you suggest a better code?

Comment: @zynkn `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)` instead of `for (const i of arr)`. IF you want to get a unique code, let use a `while loop` like `while(code === '')`, in body of while, you gen a `code`, check it, if it is duplicated , reset `code` value to `''`, or not return the `code`.

Comment: at first, I tried to use `for()` but AFAIK it doesn't work with async. and I think `while()` is a better solution but it looks like a dangerous little bit. anyway thank you so much for reply