# Unable to publish to SNS Topic, getting MessageId as undefined

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a pretty basic code snippet to test publishing of messages to SNS from Node Lambda:

```
exports.handler = async () => {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});
    let result;
    try {
        result = await new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish({
            TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:99999999999:MyTopic',
            Message: 'Body of Message 1',
            Subject: 'Message 1'
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('xxxxxxxx', err, err.stack);
        throw err;
    }
    console.info('>>>>>> ' + result.MessageId);
}
```

However, all I repeatedly get in the logs is `>>>>>> undefined`, and of course, the messages are not being published (because the queue subscribed to this is always empty). I can confirm that the Lambda function has the relevant permissions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not converting `publish` to a promise. This means that `result = await` will not work as expected.

Read my old answer for more understanding: [How to use Async and Await with AWS SDK Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328292/how-to-use-async-and-await-with-aws-sdk-javascript/51328537#51328537)

TLDR;

```
result = await new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish({
            TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:99999999999:MyTopic',
            Message: 'Body of Message 1',
            Subject: 'Message 1'
        }).promise(); // !!!
```

Comment: <<Double facepalm!>> I don't know what to say . . . thanks! :( :( :'(

Comment: Looks like this is no longer necessary, as the sdk has a promise version in `"@aws-sdk/client-sns": "^3.7.0"`, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Looks like my issue was due to one service (STS) returning credentials with PascalCasedProperties, whereas SNS expected a credentials object with camelCasedProperties.