# How to use DynamoDB DocumentClient().get() data outside of function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

After retrieving data from my table in DynamoDB, I want to be able to store that data in a variable for use outside of the `docClient` function. I recognize that the way my code is set up, it tries to `console.log()` my `userData` variable before it finishes getting the data. I believe I need to use `async/await`, but I'm not sure how. I'm not very familiar with asynchronous JavaScript. Specific examples using this code would be very helpful. Thank you for looking at this for me!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var userData;

var params = {
 TableName: 'someTableName',
 Key: {'UserID': '1'}
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    userData = data.Item;
  }
});

console.log(userData); // Output: undefined
```

Comment: I suppose [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) might be helpful. And yes, this question has been asked zounds times: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) is a direct duplicate, and I strongly suggest study its thread.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328292/how-to-use-async-and-await-with-aws-sdk-javascript

Answer (score 1):

When calling `docClient.get(...)`, also call `.promise()` on the returned value and wait for the asynchronous value via `await`.  When the result is returned to you, the item data will be in the (possibly undefined) `Item` attribute.  Finally, I expect you want to see what's in the object, so the code below inspects the result.

```js
var params = {
    TableName: 'someTableName',
    Key: {'UserID': '1'}
};

const result = await docClient.get(params).promise();
const userData = result.Item;

console.log(util.inspect(userData));
```

All of the above must be done in an `async` function.