# Mongoose pre save not update field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Video schema like this:

```
const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cover: { // image url
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }],
})
```

when I create new video, I will get cover image from 3rd site and save it to AWS S3, then update the new cover url. I have pre save middleware like this

```
videoSchema.pre("save", async function save(next) {
    try {
        await transferImagesToS3(this.cover, async (err, resp) => {
            if (err) {
                next()
            }
            if (resp.Location) { // image uploaded to AWS S3 and return new image url here
                this.cover = resp.Location // I set new url here
                next()
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```

Transfer image function

```
// transfer image to S3
export const transferImagesToS3 = (imgURL, filename, callback) => {
    request({
        url: imgURL,
        encoding: null
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) return callback(err, res);

        s3.upload({
            Bucket: 'mybucket',
            Key: `public/images/${filename}.jpeg`,
            cacheControl: 'max-age=604800',
            ContentType: res.headers['content-type'],
            ContentLength: res.headers['content-length'],
            Body: body // buffer
        }, callback)
    })
}
```

Above code, `this.cover` is image url from 3rd website. Image uploaded successful but pre save doesn't updated new image URL. What wrong with this code? Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: It shows new URL as I want, but I dont know why in DB, it isn't updated.

Comment: Yes, it's show video document. Just not saved to DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mix `callback` style with `async/await` style. An `async` function always returns a Promise, in your case `async function save(next)` will return a promise, and the `hook` will be "done" right after the promise is resolved.

[Mongoose middleware doc.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

I guess you expect the hook will wait until `transferImagesToS3` is finished, then go to the next process. But actually, your `await` keyword does not make sense because `transferImagesToS3` does not return a Promise (I guest).

We have 2 solutions:

1. Just use callback style only:

```
videoSchema.pre("save", function (next) { // remove async
  transferImagesToS3(this.cover, (err, resp) => { // remove await, async
    if (err) {
      next() // next(err) when you want to stop when upload is failed
    }
    if (resp.Location) { // image uploaded to AWS S3 and return new image url here
      this.cover = resp.Location // I set new url here
      next()
    }
  })
})
```

2. Convert `transferImagesToS3` to return a Promise (I recommend):

I use [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert a callback function to return a Promise.

```
const util = require('util')

videoSchema.pre("save", async function () { // remove next
  const resp = await util.promisify(transferImagesToS3)(this.cover) // wait
  this.cover = resp.Location
})
```

Comment: Thank you alot, I try method 1 and it works great! I'm still new in nodejs and still confuse about promise. I updated my question, added `transferImagesToS3` function. How do I convert it to promise?

Comment: @kien https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328292/how-to-use-async-and-await-with-aws-sdk-javascript/51328537#51328537